# Firebase/firestore Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i try to connect my project to firebase/firestore i receive this error

*@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.1.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project undefined does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=undefined to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.*

***here my app.js***

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import firebase from './firebase';
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function App() {

  const [works, setWorks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const ref = db.collection('portfolio');

/*  function getWorks(){
    setLoading(true);
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      querySnapshot.foreach((doc) => {
        items.push(doc.data());
      });
      setWorks(items);
      setLoading(false);
    })
  }*/

function getWorks2(){
  setLoading(true);
  ref.get().then((item) => {
    const items = item.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    setWorks(items);
    setLoading(false);
  });
}

  useEffect(() => {
   // getWorks();
    getWorks2();
  }, []);

  if(loading){
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Works</h1>
      {works.map((work) =>
        <div key={work.id}>
          <h2>{work.title}</h2>
          <p>{work.description}</p>
        </div>

      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

can you help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: can someone help me ?

Comment: hey, did you find any answers yet? I saw many similar questions but none of them is answered, I don't know why so many people are encountering this problem and no solution is being provided.